# How can we prove a graph is planar iff its subgraph is planar?

Tags: graph-theory

A is a graph, ad B is A's subgraph by deleting an edge of A. Proving forward is easy, but how can we prove backward?

Comment: If this were true, there would be an easy proof that every graph was planar: just keep deleting edges until none are left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, consider [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvrBv.png), which is the complete graph on 5 nodes with a single edge removed. It is planar, as the image shows; but famously the complete graph on 5 nodes is not planar.

Answer (score 1):

> but how can we prove backward?

We cannot, because then any graph can be shown to be planar, and that's obviously not the case.